# Why is a group a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

I'm curious as to how groups, rings, fields got their names. Did someone just start calling these structures by those names, or is there a (not entirely) arbitrary reason  for them?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/61497/264) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/71129/264)  on math.SE, and [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35286/origins-of-names-of-algebraic-structures) on MathOverflow (and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/105668/264) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/156952/264) for other terminology).

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#History

Comment: I think Galois used the word _group_ to refer to permutation groups of zeros of polynomials.  I think Arthur Cayley is the author of the modern definition, but he was probably just using established terminology rather than endorsing the idea that that's the best possible word.

Answer (score 0):

The word "group" is a translation of the French "groupe", which was first used for this purpose by Évariste Galois around 1830.

Galois considered particular permutation groups in the context of permuting the roots of an algebraic equation; his word was applied to the developing concept of an abstract group during the mid-1800s. Arthur Cayley gave the first abstract definition of a *finite group* in 1854; a fully modern notion of group was given by Walther von Dyck in 1882.

([Wikipedia: History of Group Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_group_theory)).